# Can I use a DataModule in a Console Delphi Application?

Tags: delphi

Can I use a DataModule form in a Console Delphi application?

I tried including an existing unit/form to a console Delphi application in the uses clause, but DataModule1 is resolved to nil (not initialized).

Comment: `TDataModule` is not a Form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just figured that by looking at a Form application that I simply need to do the initialization by hand:

```
Application.CreateForm(TDataModule1, DataModule1);
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested in the comments, I ended up implementing:

```
DataModule1 := TDataModule1.Create(nil)
```

Comment: Or use the Project Options dialog to set the data module as auto-create "form" which has the same effect.

Comment: Personally I don't like relying on the .dpr file to do this. Add that code to the initialization section of the data module unit. That makes the unit self-contained. And I see no reason to use `Application.CreateForm` either. Just call the constuctor, `DataModule1 := TDataModule1.Create(Application)`.

Comment: I don't get it, using `Application` in a `Console` application? Doesn't that practically defeat the purpose of a console application?

Comment: @David,@Jerry  We don't need to involve `Application` object for this. simple `DataModule1 := TDataModule1.Create(nil)` and when you're done with it `DataModule1.Free`.

Comment: @kobik That's how I would do it.

Comment: Exactly my point, why rely on `Application` at all in a console app?